# How to select distinct from one column where not existing in other columns?

Tags: mysql

I have 5 columns.

I have tried many queries but, I don't know what I am doing.

I tried this query, and many more, just to see if I could get it to work at all.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(username) FROM `tablename` WHERE username NOT IN (SELECT group1 FROM tablename)
```

tables name is tablename

cols are username | group1 | group2 | group3 | group4

I need to select the names that are in username BUT NOT in the other columns.

Is this possible? I need to place the query code into the phpmyadmin query input area.

Thank you for helping me learn this today.

Comment: Where the username is not in the group columns on the same row, or any row?

Comment: Any row. I just want to have the unique usernames from col1 that don't exist in the other columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this with a JOIN:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(t1.username)
FROM tablename t1
LEFT JOIN tablename t2
  ON t2.group1 = t1.username
LEFT JOIN tablename t3
  ON t3.group2 = t1.username
LEFT JOIN tablename t4
  ON t4.group3 = t1.username
LEFT JOIN tablename t5
  ON t5.group4 = t1.username
WHERE t2.username IS NULL
  AND t3.username IS NULL
  AND t4.username IS NULL
  AND t5.username IS NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. I will try this too although, I will need to dive into what it does so, I can understand.

Comment: I will be back tomorrow to confirm answered after I get it going.

Comment: @Markus I get error Column 'username' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: Sorry @Marcus my friend spells it differently!

Comment: I also did some searching on this error and would like to mention this is the only table in the db and those are the only columns.

Comment: @James, Sorry, I forgot to specify the table (alias) on the username field in the SELECT statement. I updated the query. Please try it now.

Comment: Well, no error but, no results either. There are usernames that exist in the first column that are not in the others, many of them. This is on a dedicated server, not shared. But, since a couple columns are over 100k lines and one is 200k lines, could it be memory related or some preset disallowing something? I know I have the latest version of php (or close) and went to verify/provide info to you but, phpmyadmin is not responding now. I think I overwhelmed it.

Comment: PHP version 5.2.14 MySQL version 5.0.92 Architecture x86_64 Operating system linux. phpmyadmin still unresponsive though. Got info from cpanel.

Comment: @James, if you're sure you entered the SQL correctly, then you probably don't have any usernames that don't appear in the group columns. Try adding a unique one for test purposes.

Comment: Yes, I verified there were unique in the 1st column. About 50 thousand should be unique. I just pasted your example into the query textarea so, I am sure all is correct. I even tried all on one line. I also studied and researched your query to learn the mechanics and yes, I think it should work as well. I will keep trying. I may just try the same query from a Perl script to see if that helps.